# Mojolicious: determine controller based on placeholder parameters

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious

I know that it's possible to write code like this.

```
$r->post('/v1/:controller/:action')
```

And mojo will call appropriate controller class.

Is it possible to do something like this in Mojo (maybe with stash):

```
$r->post('/v1/:model/:method')->to(
         action => ':method',
         controller => sub {
                          my ($captures) = @_;
                          my $controller = $captures->{'model'};
                          ...
                          return $controller;
                       }
         )
```

Comment: That would essentially eliminate the need to have any other routes. You would practically make Mojo behave like Catalyst. It should be possible, but might not be advisable